# EVP_KEY_sign gives signature length 0 unexpectedly

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm trying to sign a message with a private key in C++ with openssl. I have followed an example but for some reason I can't get EVP_PKEY_sign to work because it sets the signature length to 0. Is there anything wrong with my code?

function to sign message

```
void sign_buff(const string& priv_key_file_path, const unsigned char* buff, int buff_len, string& sig) {

    FILE* f = fopen(priv_key_file_path.c_str(), "r");
    EC_KEY* ec_key = PEM_read_ECPrivateKey(f, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(f);
    assert(1 == EC_KEY_check_key(ec_key));

    EVP_PKEY* key = EVP_PKEY_new();
    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(key, ec_key));

    EVP_PKEY_CTX* key_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key, NULL);
    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_sign_init(key_ctx));
    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(key_ctx, EVP_sha256()));
    size_t sig_len = 0;

    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_sign(key_ctx, NULL, &sig_len, buff, buff_len));
    cout << sig_len; //gives 0
    sig.assign(sig_len, 0);
    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_sign(key_ctx, (unsigned char*)&sig[0], &sig_len, buff, buff_len));


    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(key_ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(key);
}
```

I call the function with

```
 string priv="priv.pem";
 string sig;
 unsigned char buff[] = "Random message to be signed";
 sign_buff(priv, &buff[0], sizeof(buff), sig);
```

where a private key is stored in priv.pem

Comment: Are you sure that build is done in Debug, so asserts work? This code should definitely fail.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. How did you know? What's wrong? I'm trying to debug it.

Comment: When code is build for release all code behind the assert is eliminated. So correct way would be to use this style: `int r = EVP_PKEY_...()`, and then `assert(r == 1)`. The problem is that you are passing buffer to sign instead of it's hash, which you should calculate via the `EVP_MD_*` functions.

Comment: ...as a first 'proof of concept' check you may pass buffer of exactly 32 bytes length (256 bits) and see whether sign works.